# Texas Instrument CLA float inverse trick - What is its purpose

Tags: c, embedded

I have this piece of code written by somebody else that runs on a TI TMS320 Command Law Accelerator. So it's optimized in size and speed.

In order to get 1/x, the code always does something like this.

```
float32 y = __meinvf32(x); 
y = y * (2.0f - y*x); 
y = y * (2.0f - y*x);
```

I found [this thread](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000/f/171/t/365584?F28035-CLA-MEINVF32-divide-by-zero) that propose something similar, but in my case, there is no clamping at the end.

Can seomebody help me understand what is the intent behind this?

Comment: Ref [`__meinvf32()` Estimate 1/x to about 8 bits of precision.](http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRU514I/Content/SPRU514I_HTML/cla_compiler.html) explains first step.  The next 2 look like 2 rounds of  [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).   Uncertain about div by 0 issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isaac Newton figured this out.

`__meinvf32(x)` gives an approximation of 1/*x*, say 1/*x* • (1+*e*), where *e* is some small relative error.

Let *y* = 1/*x* • (1+*e*). Then, when we calculate *y* • (2 − *y*•*x*), we have:

- *y* • (2 − *y*•*x*) =
- (1/*x* • (1+*e*)) • (2 − (1/*x* • (1+*e*))•*x*) =
- 1/*x* • (1+*e*) • (2 − (1+*e*)) =
- 1/*x* • (2 + 2*e* − (1+*e*) − *e*(1+*e*)) =
- 1/*x* • (2 + 2*e* − 1 − *e* − *e* − *e*<sup>2</sup>) =
- 1/*x* • (1 − *e*<sup>2</sup>).

Since *e* is small, *e*<sup>2</sup> is even smaller. Thus, by calculating  *y* • (2 − *y*•*x*) we get an estimate of 1/*x* that is closer than before; the relative error is only −*e*<sup>2</sup> instead of *e*. Repeating this improves the estimate again (up to the limits of floating-point precision).

With some knowledge of bounds on the initial *e*, we can calculate how many repetitions are needed to get the estimate as close as desired to the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

y = e + 1/x where e is some small error.

So (2.0 - y*x) is close to 1.0 and has the effect of reducing e on each pass.